# C# Linq generic search

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I am trying to write a method for a base repository service.  The idea is I want a generic class that can be used for simple entity types hat can also be overridden for more complex entities.  I am writing a search method with the idea being that for simple entities there will be a component which will have one or more properties with fields which match properties of the entity.  if these are found then build a where linq statement to query it.  Here's what I have so far:

```
  public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
  {
     return entityRepository.GetAll();
  }

  public IQueryable<T> Search(IBaseComponent component)
  {
     IQueryable<T> all = GetAll();
     Type type = typeof(T);
     Type componentType = component.GetType();

     foreach (var componentProperty in componentType.GetProperties())
      {
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
           if (property.Name.Equals(componentProperty.Name))
           {
              var value = componentProperty.GetValue(component);

              ParameterExpression gpe = Expression.Parameter(property.DeclaringType, "a");
              var selector = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(gpe, property), Expression.Constant(value));
              var keySelector = Expression.Lambda(selector, gpe);

              var t = all.Where(keySelector);

              break;
           }
        }
      }

     var test = all.ToArray();

     return all;
  }
```

Obviously this would only theoretically work for one property at the moment.  The service itself has a type parameter (so its `BaseService<T>`).

The problem I am having is that this will not compile.  The line `all.Where(keySelector)` gives the error:

```
    'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here, they types are all correct as far as I can see.  What am I missing?  Or am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: Using var is nice and dandy. But I would highly recommend using specific types so you can see if your types are correct. Which is where your problems come from.

Comment: @Euphoric it's not the problem here.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes it is problem. Or it hides the real problem from eyes of inexperienced developer. Without var, it would be immediately noticable that types are wrong here.

Comment: @Euphoric well it doesn't compile... That's immediately noticeable !

Comment: And for answering : try (don't think it will be enough, as it seems like you have many problems in your code) : `var keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(selector, gpe);` but I don't think that gpe is builded with the right type (it should be of type T)

Comment: Why is `GetAll` a generic method since it does not have any generic usage in its implementation? The type returned is statically defined here.

Comment: This is a part of a bigger class.  GetAll is generic as it is a public method and will be called in it's own right.  I just wanted to avoid too much duplicate code.  Thanks for the help, avoiding vars would have helped me out no end here.  I thought (wrongly) that result of the lambda expression would already be the right type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression.Lambda` return type is `LambdaExpression` even if the concrete type is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` (`LambdaExpression` is the non generic base class for `Expression<T>`)

@Euphoric remark is spot on and the `var` keyword is the problem here as the reason for this error would have been obvious without it.

The correct code is something like :

```
var keySelector = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(selector, gpe);
```

Comment: This has done the trick.  I have come to rely on the var keyword far too much, I need to avoid using it as much!  The code sample is a bit messy I know, but it's only part of a rough prototype of the class to see what is possible.